# Failure to reinstall IIS7 on Windows Vista Home Premium

Tags: iis-7, installation, windows-vista, reinstall

I cannot reinstall IIS7 on a windows vista home premium laptop. A previous working IIS7 installation failed upon installation of some windows automatic updates. The updates have been removed, and IIS7 was uninstalled.

Every time the IIS7 installation is attempted (with the selection of ALL features under the Internet Information Services tree in Windows Features), an error is received at the end saying that some features were not configured correctly and that the installation will not succeed.

The installation always fails with windows rebooting saying that updates were not configured properly and uninstalling them.

Can you please assist with the possible cause of the IIS reinstallation failure. I have done a lot of forum searches, with similar reinstallation problems, but the solutions are not successful in my instance.

Thankyou for your time; I would be happy to elaborate on any points and apologise for the vagueness of this question.

What appears to be the important part of the IIS7.log error is the following:

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] [  IIS 7.0 Component Based Setup  ]

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe" /install SharedLibraries

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] < WARNING! > Failed to detect if config redirection is enabled. result=0x80070032.Assuming config is not redirected and continuing.

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] NetFrameworkConfigurationKey key container already exists

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] Set ACLs on NetFrameworkConfigurationKey

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] iisWasKey key container already exists

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] iisWasKey user key already exists

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] iisConfigurationKey already exists

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] < !!FAIL!! > Install of component SharedLibraries result=0x80070032

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] < !!FAIL!! > COMPONENT::ExecuteCommand result=0x80070032

[01/20/2012 19:40:40] [ End of IIS 7.0 Component Based Setup ]

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] [  IIS 7.0 Component Based Setup  ]

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe" /launch C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe reset config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] < WARNING! > Failed to detect if config redirection is enabled. result=0x80070032.Assuming config is not redirected and continuing.

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] Launching command C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe, with params C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe reset config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] < !!FAIL!! > LaunchCommand result=0x80070032

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] [ End of IIS 7.0 Component Based Setup ]

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] [  IIS 7.0 Component Based Setup  ]

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe" /launch C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe reset config -section:system.applicationHost/listenerAdapters

[01/20/2012 19:40:42] < WARNING! > Failed to detect if config redirection is enabled. result=0x80070032.Assuming config is not redirected and continuing.

The following have been tried, with the same error IIS7.log error:

a) Uninstall Windows Process Activation Service, reboot, before attempting reinstall of IIS7

b) Administrator command line to try and fully wipe IIS7 install before another reinstall failure

start /w pkgmgr.exe /uu:IIS-WebServerRole;WAS-WindowsActivationService

Answer (score 2):

Better to first `uninstall` the installed IIS using following Command run with the admin privilege in CMD and install IIS using Web Platform Installer.It will be easy to manage.

```
start /w pkgmgr /uu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASP;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-Security;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
```

Helpful [Link](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/web-platform-installer/using-the-microsoft-web-platform-installer)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open regidit, navigate to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP]:
        a) Change Start from 4 ( disabled) to 3 ( automatically)
        b) Delete "NoRun" key if this key exists
2. Reboot the server.
3. Reinstall IIS7 again.

from
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/01/10/iis7-re-installation-failed-due-to-http-service-disabled.aspx